# How to capitalize the last character of a string vector?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I just started using R and I wanted to know how to create a function that will capitalize the last character of a string vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R regex:

```
words <- c("hello", "world")

# Last character of last word in vec element: 
gsub("(\\w$)", "\\U\\1", words, perl = TRUE)

sentences <- c("hello world", "hello friend")

# Last character of sentence: 
gsub("(\\w$)", "\\U\\1", sentences, perl = TRUE)

# Last character of each word in the sentence: 
gsub("(\\w\\s+|\\w$)", "\\U\\1", sentences, perl = TRUE)
```